Deciphering BHS Masorah parva


In trying to understand the critical apparatus of Psalm 94:19. I understand the final ﬥ refers to the word occurring only once as indicated in the Veteris Testamenti Concordantiae Hebraicae Atque Chaldaicae (see below attachment). However, my question deals in deciphering the Masorah parva before the hapax legomenon designation indicated the final ﬥ. According to the Solomon Mandelkern reference, the word defined as "cogitationes" occurs both in Ps. 94,19 as well as Ps. 139,23 and so it's technically not a hapax which, I suppose, is elaborated by the Hebrew text in the margin, the reason for this inquiry. The second hebrew word, "inward part , midst" as defined in Brown-Driver-Briggs) is also found in

There are three Masoretic notes here, on three different words. They need to be read one at a time, and in order. The one you are reading refers to the word תנחומיך. The note on the word שרעפי actually says it appears twice (ב'), with a difference in vowels (שַׂרְעַפַּי  here vs. שַׂרְעַפָּי there).

Beat me to the answer :-) Any idea what the יא means? I couldn't figure that part out

Is the Hebrew, קמ (with a small dot over the mem) referirng to the 139,23 reference then? What about the third instance with the א? I'm assuming numerals, 7 and 8, are referring to different manuscripts.

@Loani and ed huff - the answer to both questions is given by EraserX. The יא is 11, the קמ is kamatz, the פת is patach. I don't see a 7 and 8.

As you indicated in your question, there are three masoretic notes on the side:
1) for the word שרעפי: the note ב חד פת וחד קמ indicates two (instances of this word), one with a patach (under the פ) and one with a kamatz (under the פ) - as you pointed out, the two instances occur here and also in תהלים קלט:כג
2) for the word בְּקִרְבִּי: the note יא indicates the eleven occurrences where this word/lettering occurs with the stream of vowels: shva, chirik, shva, chirik - one in דברים, one in יהושע, one in ישעיהו, one in ירמיהו, five in תהלים, two in איכה (there's also one instance of בִּקְרֹבַי with different vowels)
3) for the word תנחומיך: as you correctly indicated, ל means that this word only occurs once
You also might be interested in this nice listing from Mikraot Gedolot HaKeter which has a helpful breakdown for decoding the meaning of many of the masoretic symbols

Thanks EraserX for taking the time to unravel the side notes: your explanation has been most helpful and I'll definitely look into that reference work you mentioned. Again, Thank you!

One additional question. In the Veteris Testamenti Concordantiae, I notice the abbreviation 'cs.' next to an apparent hapax legomenon in Psalm 101:3 (Page 923 in Mandelkern's text). Would you know what that stand for?

I believe the following might be a good guess:
Seems that Mandelkern often uses "cs." when an entry is accompanied by associated similar entries.
I searched Google for: latin abbreviation cs. and got:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/c.s. Abbreviation of cum suis. with his (party), and associates (see next comment)

acc. to ChatGPT "what does the latin term "cum suis" mean in a reference book such as a concordance?"
The Latin term "cum suis" translates to "with its own" or "with their own" in English. In the context of a reference book like a concordance, "cum suis" often means "with its related entries" or "with its associates". It suggests that the main entry is accompanied by other related entries or references.
For example, if a term is listed in a concordance cum suis, it might include not only the primary term but also variations, derivatives, or associated terms relevant to the topic or context.

On the other hand, when I asked: what does the latin abbreviation"cs." mean in a reference book such as a concordance?
ChatGPT responded:
In a reference book like a concordance, the Latin abbreviation "cs." typically stands for "conferatur secum" or just "confer secum", meaning "compare with itself" or "compare internally".
It is used to direct the reader to compare related passages or entries within the same text or concordance. This abbreviation serves as a guide to cross-referencing within the work.

That makes sense as there are two others citations (Genesis 50:20; Proverbs 21:3) that each contain a hapax for the verb עשׂה ('to do'). Again, thanks!
